# Windows 10 show garbage characters

Tags: windows-10

My windows 10 show garbage characters, I guess I didn't do anything special, but when I start my computer, it looks like this now. is there anything I can do right now?[image]

[image]
[image]

Comment: Did you change the language or anything like that?

Comment: I didn't change language, but I think I installed a font before last shut down. But I did install fonts on windows 7 or 8, never had this problem before.

Comment: Oh ok. Well try this, Control Panel → Appearance and Personalization → under **Fonts** select **Change Font Settings** → Restore default font settings.

Comment: @MC10 I'm not sure if you could help me take a screenshot of this page, I'm not able to recognize the characters.

Comment: Oh yeah, I'll post an answer with screenshots.

Comment: @MC10 thanks a lot, I'm trying now. appreciate your help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/26551/discussion-between-timeless-and-mc10).

Answer (score 9):

Since OP cannot read the menus, use the images for reference.

Open **Control Panel** and go to **Appearance and Personalization**.

[image: Appearance]

Now under **Fonts** select **Change Font Settings**.

[image: Fonts]

In the new window that opens, under **Font Settings**, click **Restore default font settings**.

[image: Restore]

Comment: Dang, that's unfortunate. Is there any system restore you can do? How did you install the font?

Comment: I double clicked a .ttc file and the font be installed. I guess it is the decoding part is wrong.

Comment: Oh... that's a Mac OS X font file. You would have to [convert it](http://superuser.com/questions/114603/how-to-install-os-x-ttc-font-on-windows-error-ttc-does-not-appear-to-be-a). I'm not sure how to restore your system though. Try running `sfc/ scannow` or you may have to do a reset. Do you have any system restores available?

Comment: yes, didn't think much, our designer put the font inside the dropbox, I just made a try to install. I guess I will try to reinstall or rollback to win 8.1.

Comment: @MC10: .ttc fonts are not necessarily "OS X font files" – they're regular TrueType "collections", Microsoft itself has shipped several such fonts for the past few years, starting with Cambria.ttc in Office 2007. I think even WinXP supports that.

Comment: @grawity this has occurred when I deleted C:\Windows\Fonts, could OP just replace that directory with a good one?

Comment: @MichaelBailey I'm not sure but that is probably possible. I think he mentioned in chat that he eventually chose to rollback to Windows 8.1 for the time being though.

Answer (score 1):

I've just had this same problem. I was able to fix it by reinstalling all fonts from a font directory I keep as a back-up.

Now, of course the question is: how do you get to this back-up font directory? :-) I was lucky enough to have stored that directory on a home server, so I could access it from another computer and simply count the n-th directory from the top, and so forth.

Good luck!

Comment: You could also do this by booting from recovery media and copying the Fonts folder from a working computer.

Answer (score 0):

Just came across this problem. The font is Marlett.ttf. Uninstall of the font would not work from settings. Manually deleting the file did not work. I removed it from the fonts folder via booting to safe mode or a Hirens boot disc (sorry cant recall) and deleting it from the Windows Fonts folder.  I set the fonts to default in Settings. Ran a SFC and the font came back. I redid the delete, then added the default font registry file to set it to Segoe. Then the font was gone for good.