# All text changed to symbols in Windows 10 - Emergency

Tags: fonts, windows-10, user-interface

I booted my computer and now this is what I'm looking at.

[image]

It's like my system font was set to [Marlett](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marlett).

Furthermore, certain apps are unaffected, such as Chrome, Settings, (most of) TeamViewer, etc.

What did I do, and more importantly, how do I fix it?

**Edit:** With some help from @MC10, I was able to determine that installing a TTC font file is what borked my install. That being said, I also can't perform a system restore because during the upgrade process from 8.1, System Protection was disabled on all of my drives.

Comment: There was a user with a similar problem. Did you install any fonts or change language settings recently?

Comment: I did install a font, come to think of it. Let me see if I can hunt it down and remove it.

Comment: @mc10 My Fonts window shows three fonts, none of which I can tell what they are. I'm afraid to remove any of them in case it gets worse.

Comment: I found the question here: http://superuser.com/questions/949956/windows-10-show-garbage-characters He installed a ttc font which is usually for Mac but not necessarily. The way he solved it was rolling back to Windows 8.1. I'm not sure if it's possible to repair it. Do you have any system restore points?

Comment: I honestly have no idea. Where would I check?

Comment: http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4588-system-restore-windows-10-a.html

Comment: Apparently System Protection was disabled when I upgraded from 8.1. Awesome! And I can't read any of the text in the window is opened to try and turn it back on. **Edit** Managed to find a tutorial with images. Still doesn't help the issue though.

Comment: Try this: http://superuser.com/questions/695635/windows-8-1-missing-font-files-after-restart

Comment: @MC10 I'll give that a shot. Luckily I have access to a laptop right now that's also running Windows 10.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/27034/discussion-between-mc10-and-darkwolffe).

Comment: I don't think that'll be necessary at this point. I managed to get it to boot. That other guide seemed to work out okay, but I missed the last step and couldn't boot to the login screen so I ended do a reset. Thanks for your help though.

Answer (score -1):

HI Dude You can resolve this problem by installing any new common fonts in to the font library.If you check your library you can see only 3 set of fonts... that's the problem.As per my case i saw this problem when i reboot my laptop after installing some fonts(material fonts and one ttc font also i think... let me confirm that and i will update it