# Windows 10 Default font messed up Missing fonts

Tags: windows-10, fonts

So as you can see here:

[image: http://imgur.com/K6XA0lo]

My fonts messed up for some reason. It was fine yesterday though.

I've already tried sfc /scannow which didn't do anything and I can't change the font via appearances because... I can't read what it says when the window opens..

Any help would be very appreciated :)

Edit: I did some more digging, and according to InDesign I'm simply just missing 90% of my fonts? I don't know if that helps though.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't already, try **resetting font settings** if you haven't already.

That *should* fix corrupted fonts and add back missing Windows fonts, to my knowledge.

[image: Resetting Font Settings]

Comment: Right I've been trying that, but I cant seem to figure out how to get to that particular button, I can see the menu with the font folder to get to that button, but the 3 options i get to click all do something different? I think I need this window, but I can't seem to figure it out. It doesn't change anything for me  http://imgur.com/ee7EuBy

Comment: Yes, that screen is it. Sorry about not providing clear instruction of how to get there in your situation. Almost forgot you had to deal with that. If the button didn't work then I'm not quite sure what you could do other than reinstall windows.

Comment: Thats alright, I appreciate the help, and I can navigate with only a bit of trouble as long as I know where to go. But you don't happen to know what I'm supposed to click? I've been trying all kinds of things but nothing does anything for me.

Comment: Based on your screenshot, that seems to be the same page as my screenshot. All you click is "Restore default font settings". Or in your case, the button. You don't need to press OK or anything. I would just press the button then restart.

Comment: Alright, so i've restarted with no change I'm afraid. I'm going to try getting the fonts from another computer and see if that helps.

Comment: Update: Got Arial from my brothers computer, seems to fix most fonts. should be able to navigate normally now woo

Comment: @insane That suggestion is already covered in the duplicate question [Windows 10 show garbage characters](http://superuser.com/q/949956)

Comment: Clicking that button __will not__ restore missing fonts.

Answer (score 0):

Right the fix I've found is to get the Arial font from any computer and install it. It looks like it won't fix it but just go over anything with your mouse and the words should appear, this way you can reset your fonts because you can actually navigate again.

You'll have to remember where you put your arial font on your usb or whatever you use though, put it in a separate map or on an empty usb as copying the arial font turns into multiple files.

edit: Seems to still do the weird font on restart