# How to access fonts in windows 10

Tags: windows-10

I just want to open the fonts installed in windows 10, I remember I tried before to type just "fonts" in the start menu search but now when I try to search I dont find anything !!

[image]

So how I can access the windows fonts ?

Comment: Checked : `Control Panel / Appearance and Personalization / Fonts`? Possible similar topic: http://superuser.com/questions/949956/windows-10-show-garbage-characters

Comment: Mine is in Control Panel>All Control Panel Items>Fonts, or C:\Windows\Fonts

Comment: why fonts does not appear in the search result when I open the settings ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this** to fix your search:

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> then type `rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL srchadmin.dll`

This will open indexing options. Once open, click "**Advanced**"

Then **rebuild your index**:

[image]

*(I might restart after rebuilding the index, by the way)*

---

**If that doesn't work**, you could always try running `sfc /scannow` in an elevated command prompt by searching `cmd` then pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: Thanks, one question please just for information where Windows store indexing information for files and folders ?

Comment: `Windows.edb` is the database file of the indexing service located at: `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Search\Data\Applications\Windows`. [(Source)](http://windows7themes.net/en-us/what-is-windows-edb-can-i-delete-it-or-change-its-location/)

Answer (score 1):

Get the Run box with <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and type `shell:fonts`.