# Avenir Next font corrupting fonts

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, file-corruption

Every time I install Avenir Next on my PC it corrupts my fonts (showing random symbols instead), requiring me to delete the font registry entries, reinstall all of my fonts, and reboot.
I still can't find out why the font is corrupting my font folder and I need to use this font for a specific project.

The same problem as listed in [this page](https://superuser.com/questions/714265/windows-8-1-text-showing-up-as-random-artifacts) however that doesn't provide a fix so that you can use Avenir Next, only how to restore Windows back to normal.

Any thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: There is one report that it is Avenir Next Condensed that is causing the issue. Is it possible for you to install specific fonts that you actually need from the whole font family?

Comment: http://fontfamily.io/avenir_next says that Avenir Next is **not** supported on Windows ...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install OS X \*.TTC font on Windows? Error: "\*.TTC does not appear to be a valid font"](http://superuser.com/q/114603) according to which "Please note, that Windows does not directly support TTC fonts, according to Adobe". Answers include several options to convert `.ttc` to `.ttf`

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install OS X \*.TTC font on Windows? Error: "\*.TTC does not appear to be a valid font"](http://superuser.com/questions/114603/how-to-install-os-x-ttc-font-on-windows-error-ttc-does-not-appear-to-be-a)

Comment: [Convert or extract TTC font to TTF - how to?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15455895)